# Decreasing random number... logical error

Tags: java, while-loop

Basically what I am trying to do with this program is have the system generate a random number then assign that number to another variable. if the number is above 20, then a while loop will start until the value of the variable(which was determined by the random number) is less than 20 which will then end the program. the problem is that the while loop seems to go on for ever :( . Help please

This is the code:

```
package innocence;
import java.util.Scanner;

class GS1{

    public static void main(String[]args){


        int ranNum = (int)( Math.random()*25);
        int num=ranNum;
        System.out.println(num);
        while(num > 20){

        System.out.println("Not acceptable");   

        num= num --;
        }       
    }    
}
```

Comment: According to your description, all you need to do is check if the generated number is larger than 20, and if it is, replace the value with 20. There's no reason to decrement it in a loop because it will always end up at 20.

Comment: The random number will never be greater than 20, since Math.random() returns a random value between 0 and 1 (exclusive). Also, just use "num--" to decrement the variable.

Comment: Also you should put the random generate inside the loop, since in the loop you are just decreasing the number, it will always exit the loop when the number is 20 (which is not a random number).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you use a [postfix decrement operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.3) :

```
num = num--;
```

The JLS I linked specify that

> The result of the postfix decrement expression is not a variable, but
>   a value.

That call simply re-assign num it current value as the assignation is done before the decrement, then perform the decrement which result in a value that is never assigned as your variable was already assigned.

You could confirm this by adding a print statement in the loop which would always print the same value.

```
System.out.println(num);
```

Each time you re-iterate the loop, num still have it previous value.

You could fix this by using a [prefix decrement operator](http://15.15.2.%20Prefix%20Decrement%20Operator%20--) :

```
num = --num;
```

But you should instead simply use  :

```
num--;
```

which is way simpler.